# MySQL: Invalid use of group function updating two columns with update/select

Tags: mysql

I am trying to update two columns within a table from a select statment in MySQL 5.7.
The error I get is "invalid use of group function"

Stmt:

```
UPDATE
    catalog mpc
JOIN
    reviews mpr  ON mpr.merchant_id = mpc.MERCHANT_ID and mpr.sku = mpc.ARTICLE_ID
SET
    mpc.RATING = avg(mpr.rating),
    mpc.RATINGS = count(mpr.rating)
WHERE
        mpr.MERCHANT_ID = 1
    AND mpr.sku = '133';
```

It looks about right to me, what could be the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must aggregate first in `reviews` and then join to `catalog`:

```
UPDATE catalog mpc
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT merchant_id, sku, AVG(rating) avg_rating, COUNT(rating) count_rating
  FROM reviews 
  WHERE merchant_id = 1 AND sku = '133'
  GROUP BY merchant_id, sku
) mpr ON mpr.merchant_id = mpc.MERCHANT_ID and mpr.sku = mpc.ARTICLE_ID
SET mpc.RATING = mpr.avg_rating,
    mpc.RATINGS = mpr.count_rating
```